# Python program not ending

Tags: python

Im a total python noob and Im trying to figure out why my program doesn't end when I input "0". It just starts the menu over again.

```
def menu():
    print('\n\n\n\n')
    print('List Processing Program Menu')
    print('0 to exit')
    print('1 to view data')
    print('2 to append data')

    while(1):
        try:
            choice = -1
            while(choice < 0 or choice > 2):
                choice = int(input('Please enter a valid number choice '))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('Enter an integer number for your menu selection')
        return choice

def main():
    while(1):
        choice = menu()
        if(choice == 0):
            break
main()
```

Comment: No value is ever returned from `menu` because your `return` statement is inside of the `while` loop that you `break` out of before you get to it. Hence, inside of your `main`, choice is always `None`. If you de-indent the `return` statement this will work as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(choice < 0 or choice > 2):
    choice = int(input('Please enter a valid number choice '))
    break
```

Your problem is here. The `while` loop is broken out of and `None` is always returned (there is an implicit `return` of `None` at the end of every Python function).

You can clean up your code as follows:

```
def menu():
    print('\n\n\n\n')
    print('List Processing Program Menu')
    print('0 to exit')
    print('1 to view data')
    print('2 to append data')

    choice = None
    while choice not in [0, 1, 2]:
        try:
            choice = int(input('Please enter a valid number choice '))
        except ValueError:
            print('Enter an integer number for your menu selection')
    return choice
```

Answer (score 1):

No value is ever returned from `menu` because your `return` statement is inside of the `while` loop that you `break` out of before you get to it. Hence, inside of your `main`, choice is always `None`.

If you de-indent the `return` statement this will work as you expect.

```
def menu():
    print('\n\n\n\n')
    print('List Processing Program Menu')
    print('0 to exit')
    print('1 to view data')
    print('2 to append data')

    while(1):
        try:
            choice = -1
            while(choice < 0 or choice > 2):
                choice = int(input('Please enter a valid number choice '))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('Enter an integer number for your menu selection')

    return choice

def main():
    while(1):
        choice = menu()
        if(choice == 0):
            break
main()
```

If you want to be concise, you can remove all of your `try/except` statements because you never actually need to execute those anyhow.

```
def menu():
    choice = -1
    while choice < 0 or choice > 2:
        choice = int(input('Please enter a valid number choice'))

    return choice   


def main():
    choice = -1
    while choice != 0:
        choice = menu()
```

Answer (score 0):

Right after the `while (choice < 0 or choice > 2):` loop you say `break`, but the `return choice` is inside of the `while(1)` loop.  That means that your function will by implication return `None`, not `choice`.  You just need to un-indent the `return choice` line.

Answer (score 0):

Your `menu()` function returns `None` because your `return` statement is inside your `while` loop, which you `break` out of when the entry is valid.

Unindent your `return` statement so it lines up with `while`, or better yet, just `return` from inside the loop instead of using `break`.

Answer (score 0):

You are never returning `choice`, because it is inside your first while loop. When you break out of that while loop, you just return None since there is no specific return specified. You have two options here:

Move the return outside of the while loop, or do something like this:

```
    try:
        choice = -1
        while(choice < 0 or choice > 2):
            return int(input('Please enter a valid number choice '))
    except ValueError:
        print('Enter an integer number for your menu selection')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent the break when you are reading the choice, or else your menu function will always return None.

```
    try:
        choice = -1
        while(choice < 0 or choice > 2):
            choice = int(input('Please enter a valid number choice '))
            break
    except ValueError:
        print('Enter an integer number for your menu selection')
```